# How to rewrite (change the visual appearance only) my websites URL's using .htaccess in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I would like to re-write (change) the visual appearance of my site URL's, NOT the URL's location or destination.

The current re-write rule doesn't seem to be having any effect on my site URL's.

**Current URL:**

```
sell-house-fast/?location=ilford
```

**Desired URL:**

```
sell-house-fast/ilford
```

**Current Code:**

```
RewriteRule ^sell-house-fast/ilford/$ sell-house-fast/?location=ilford [NC,L]
```

**Conclusion:**

My URL's are just the same. The code in my .htaccess file hasn't changing a thing.

I'm only guessing, maybe it has something to do with the special characters?

Any ideas/answers would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to use the new URLs on your website. So `sell-house-fast/ilford` should be in `href`. Are you doing that? You also might have an issue with the `/`. That should be optional, and you likely want it dynamic. `RewriteRule ^sell-house-fast/(.+)$ sell-house-fast/?location=$1 [NC,L]`

Comment: @user3783243 I'll give that a go. Thanks!

Comment: @user3783243 That's fixed it. Changing the nav__link href="" to the new desired URL fixed the problem. I had previously managed to get it working this way. Trying to find the bug i created a mess. Thanks!

Comment: From halfway down [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20563773/369434) in the [dupe question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained): `mod_rewrite does not magically make all your URLs "pretty"`.